# Getting blue color around images in the IE-6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have one issue in IE-6, I am getting blue color around images in the IE-6.

http://phone.invox.com/widgetconfig/mcwidget8/test.html

Comment: I don't see *anything* on the linked page, so I don't know what you're even talking about.

Comment: click on "Call Us" button in the right side page.

Comment: Ah, I see. Chrome is rendering that about halfway off the page (I guess that's something else to check), and my browser window wasn't perfectly lined up...

Answer (score 4):

If those images are links, then you're seeing the default image link styling.

Add a bit of CSS as follows:

```
img {border:none;}
```

That will get rid of the default border style.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens in IE when an img is placed in an anchor tag.

you can remove blue border by using following css:

```
a img {
border: none;
}
```

This will remove blue border around img from IE without effecting chrome, FF (as there is no blue border around img in them) etc.

Hope this helps.